# Linux Shell "paste" command - guaranteed line-based interleaving?

Tags: linux, bash, sh, file-descriptor, process-substitution

I'm using the `paste` command in the Linux shell (`bash`) for the purposes of interleaving the output of two commands, on an every-other-line basis.  Empirically, my code seems to work, but I'm wondering whether `paste` has guaranteed behavior of alternating lines of output from each command.  If I ran my below code 100 times, and one of the commands ran slower than the other one time, could I get two lines of output from one command before the other command caught up?.  I don't see any documentation of this in the `man` page on my systems (OS X or Ubuntu 18.04), it just seems to work...

Find the sample code below (FYI, it's producing a formatted hex dump in a format I like):

```
# Version 1
paste -d "\n" <(
    cat "${largeFile}" | 
    LC_CTYPE=C tr -c '[:print:]' '.' | 
    sed -E $'s/.{30}/&\\\n/g' | 
    sed 's/./&  /g'
) <(
    xxd -p "${largeFile}" |
    sed 's/../& /g'
)
```

Output:

```
G  I  F  8  9  a  .  .  q  .  w  .  .  !  .  3  C  r  e  a  t  e  d     w  i  t  h     t  
47 49 46 38 39 61 c7 01 71 00 77 ff 00 21 fe 33 43 72 65 61 74 65 64 20 77 69 74 68 20 74 
...
```

This question is sort of the opposite topic of the behavior of `cat` when you give it two streams: `cat` nominally prints from one stream first (perhaps all of its lines), then the other.  For example:

```
# Echo buffers at 8096 characters on my system
numLines=$(( 2 * (8096 + 36) / 37 ))

# Make some dummy text that is double the size of echo's buffer
longText1="$( seq -f "Line %04.0f: $( printf "%s" {a..z} )" 1 ${numLines} )"
longText2="$( seq -f "Line %04.0f: $( printf "%s" {A..Z} )" 1 ${numLines} )"

# Print two streams simultaneously and check for interleaving
cat <(echo "${longText1}") <(echo "${longText2}")
```

The above code prints all lines from `longText1` (lower case alphabet) first "most of the time", then the text from `longText2` (upper case alphabet).  But if you run it enough times, that isn't always true.  Refer to this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476089/464414

So for `cat`, interleaving behavior for two streams is actually undefined, but you could easily guess that the behavior is "it doesn't interleave" based on empirical testing.  What about for `paste` -- is the behavior guaranteed? I worry because I don't see anything about that written in the `man` page.

---

**SIDEBAR:**

In case anyone runs into this post searching for keywords "hexdump formatting" or something, here is one more version of the code that sometimes runs a little faster.  Only use if the answers say it's safe ;-)

```
# Version 2
paste -d "\n" <(
    cat "${largeFile}" | 
    LC_CTYPE=C tr -c '[[:print:]]' '.' | 
    fold -bw 1 | 
    tr "\n" " " | 
    fold -bw 2 | 
    tr "\n" " " | 
    fold -bw 90
) <(
    xxd -p "${largeFile}" | 
    fold -bw2 | 
    tr -s "\n" " " | 
    fold -bw 90
)
```

Or:

```
formatAscii=\
'/0 "%010_ad  |\t" '\
'30/1 " %_p " '\
'"\n"'
formatHex=\
'/0 "%010_ad  |\t" '\
'30/1 "%02x " '\
'"\n"'
hexdump -v -e "${formatAscii}" -e "${formatHex}" "${largeFile}"
```

Comment: `The above code prints all lines from...But if you run it enough times, that isn't always true.` ? No, every time it's the same. `So for cat, interleaving behavior for two streams is actually undefined,` No, it's defined. `What about for paste -- is the behavior guaranteed?` What do you mean by "you don't see"? The man page states: `Write lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines from each FILE` , seems clear enough. (Also, the word "guaranteed" - GNU programs are licensed under GPL, there is no warranty of any kind.)

Comment: @KamilCuk - Disagree on the `cat` interleaving.  Refer to this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476089/464414 I've seen it myself too, with the type of test I posted above.  My man page for `paste` isn't worded quite that way (Mac OS X, so BSD), but reading it again, I do think it might be OK: I found the phrase "*concatenates the corresponding lines*".  I'm OK without a warranty lol ;-)

Comment: There are no processes running in the background... you are linking an unrelated code. Output interleaving is there unrelated to cat - related to processes running at the same time. Did you read the answer there?

Comment: Overall, I do not know what you expect - it's harsh, but I can only guess that your questions come from misunderstanding how stuff works. I can offer an advice only to learn as much as possible. 
Read the answer there - it explains in good details process buffering and pipe buffering. But _do not stop there_ - research other sources, also read glibc sources and inspect how process buffing works  and inspect linux kernel sources to see how pipe buffering works.

Comment: But still, you are linking a question that deals with 3 separate background processes writing to the same file descriptor connected to `cat`. That is just unrelated to your example, where `bash` creates two fifos connected to two processes that write to them and then spawns `cat` process that reads from one fifo and then the other. That is... unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

> guaranteed line-based interleaving?

GNU tools are licensed any GPL license that gives no warranty of any kind. BSD utilities are under BSD license and also give no warranty of any kind. There are licensed POSIX operating systems that might give you a guarantee of the behavior.

> guaranteed line-based interleaving?

There is no guaranty of any kind. Yes, this is how this utility work.

> if you run it enough times, that isn't always true

Unless cosmic rays or other very highly unlikely events do not mess with your hardware, that is always true.

> is the behavior guaranteed?

There is no guaranty of any kind. Yes, this is how it work.

---

All programs, shell and kernel you are using are open source. Inspect their source to become familiar with how they work.

The "most important" description of standard utilities is in POSIX, see [POSIX cat](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) and [POSIX paste](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/paste.html).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering whether paste has guaranteed behavior of alternating lines of output from each command

This is by definition how `paste` is supposed to work, and the only reason it doesn't work that way, is that your `paste` command is broken, i.e. it does not comply to [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html) which states "The paste utility shall concatenate the corresponding lines of the given input files, and write the resulting lines to standard output."

**In other words**, `paste file1 file2` reads one line from file1 and one line from file2, then it outputs the concatenation of the two lines, then it repeats these operations with the next line.

> If (...) one of the commands ran slower than the other one time, could I get two lines of output from one command before the other command caught up?

No. `paste file1 file2` always concatenate in the order of the input files (file1 then file2), and it always proceed to the concatenation only *after* it has read one line from each input file.

The only expected exception is when EOF is met (one file has less lines than the other) and the behavior is well defined by POSIX: "If an end-of-file condition is detected on one or more input files, but not all input files, paste shall behave as though empty lines were read from the files on which end-of-file was detected"

> I don't see any documentation of this in the man page on my systems

If a line takes time to be read, `paste` will wait until it is fully available (i.e. until the ending `\n` has been read or EOF is met). This is the expected behavior when your manual page states "xxx reads a line of input". If there is a timeout or any special condition that may disrupt the normal behavior (i.e. make the read abort), then and only then will it be mentioned in the manual.

> This question is sort of the opposite topic of the behavior of cat when you give it two streams: cat nominally prints from one stream first (perhaps all of its lines), then the other.

Yes, this is how `cat` is defined in [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html): "The cat utility shall read files in sequence and shall write their contents to the standard output in the same sequence."

> But if you run it enough times, that isn't always true.

No. You may run `cat` 10 billion times, it will always run as defined by POSIX. If your `cat file1 file2` sometimes outputs file2 before file1, then your `cat` is broken.